# В чем причина SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Поставил итератор на каждые 10 значений новая строка:

```
if i == 10:
    ls.append(\n)
```

Ошибка:

```
ls.append(\n)
                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Как это правильно можно сделать/исправить ошибку на python 2.7?

P.S: Вывод такой программы: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, ...]
Вот сам код:

```
ls=[]
i=0
for z in range(1,1000,1):
    i+=1
    x=z#;print x
    inv_x=int(str(x)[::-100])#;print inv_x
    a=inv_x-x#;print a
    inv_a=int(str(a)[::-100])#;print inv_a
    b=a+inv_a#;print b
    ls.append(b)
print ls
```

Comment: ls.append('\n')

Comment: Помещайте сообщение об ошибке в заголовок, так как (снова) ваша задача не имеет прямого отношения к ошибке (то есть "как исправить SyntaxError" не имеет никакого отношения к "как вставить новую строку через каждые 10 символов" -- это совсем другой вопрос).

Comment: похожий (на заголовок) вопрос: [Insert a newline character every 64 characters using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2657693/4279)

Comment: '\n' - не подходит - нужно, что бы была новая строка через каждые 10 значений (для удобного просмотра).

Comment: @ALPHA, напишите, что именно нужно получить результате? Список, напечатанный по 10 чисел в строке? Это уж точно не делается вставкой '\n' в список. Напишите, именно так, как вы хотите видеть результат.

Comment: @insolor, Так, что бы его можно было удобно посмотреть (например по 10 числе в строке)
Например:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10, (новая строка)
 -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -20,(новая строка)
 -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, ...](новая строка)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите конкатенировать элементы list`а с указанием separate symbol:

```
text = '\n'.join(['a','b','c'])
```

Если вам надо конкатенировать list в котором уже есть элементы '\n':

```
text = ''.join(['a', 'b', '\n', 'c', 'd'])
```

Comment: `ls=[]
i=0
for z in range(1,1000,1):
    i+=1
    x=z#;print x
    inv_x=int(str(x)[::-100])#;print inv_x
    a=inv_x-x#;print a
    inv_a=int(str(a)[::-100])#;print inv_a
    b=a+inv_a#;print b
    ls.append(b)
print ls`

Comment: этот код нужно в свой вопрос выложить

Comment: @ALPHA, добавьте этот код в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Удали пробелы после добавления "\n)"
Если это pycharm. Alt+ctrl+L

Comment: там нету пробелов

Comment: @ALPHA: `ls.append('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно именно разбить текст на строки для удобного просмотра, лучше воспользоваться функциями из модуля [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/textwrap.html), тогда и перенос по словам будет правильный. Пример:

```
from textwrap import fill
print(fill('qwerty asfgh zxcvhb', width=15))
```

Вывод:

```
qwerty asfgh
zxcvhb
```

Если "слова" слишком длинные, чтобы поместиться в заданной ширине, то они будут разбиты на куски не указанной ширины:

```
print(fill('11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111', width=10))
```

Вывод:

```
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
111
```

Comment: только там не текст а цифры

Comment: @ALPHA, добавьте пример текста, который вам нужно разбить, в вопрос.

Comment: `ls=[]
i=0
for z in range(1,1000,1):
    i+=1
    x=z#;print x
    inv_x=int(str(x)[::-100])#;print inv_x
    a=inv_x-x#;print a
    inv_a=int(str(a)[::-100])#;print inv_a
    b=a+inv_a#;print b
    ls.append(b)
print ls`

Comment: @ALPHA, нажмите кнопку "править" под вопросом, и вставьте код туда, а не раскидывайте его по комментариям.

Answer (score 0):

Как есть:

```
ls.append(\n)
```

Как надо:

```
ls.append('\n')
```

Функция `.append()` принимает строку. Вы забыли поставить кавычки, и поэтому ваш `\n` - это просто обратный слеш и несуществующее имя `n`, но не строка.